# deploy folder in jboss5?

Tags: java, jboss

I wanted to know in which folder the jboss extracts the war which we have deployed? Because I want to know whether the particular class which I changed has been picked by it or not?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

under: `${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default(if you use default)/tmp/`.

More decent way you could open jboss admin console to check the application status.